# Google App Engine: template not working when displaying html form

Tags: google-app-engine

In my python code I have

```
    the_button = '''<form action="/edit" method="get" >
                    <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
                    </form>'''

    template_values = { 'the_button':the_button }
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'the.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

The problem is that when I see in the page it will show the button but non-clickable, then when I view the page source of the html it doesn't show the code.

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What's in your `the.html` template?

Comment: In the template {{ the_button }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Webapp](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/) is probably escaping your raw html.
Try to add a `safe` filter like this:

```
{{  the_button|safe }}
```

From Django [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe):

> **safe**
>      Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output.
>      When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect.

**EDIT:**
Unluckily Google App Engine out of the box runs Django 0.96 that does not have that feature.
You have two options:

1. Install a more recent version of Django ([Django-NonRel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel#documentation))
2. Ask yourself why you need to pass a raw risky html snippet from the controller to the view.
   I would move that button to the view instead, allowing the controller to show it or not using a simple `show_button` boolean variable.

In the controller:

```
show_button = true
template_values = { 'show_button':show_button }
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'the.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

In `the.html`

```
{%if show_button  %}
    <form action="/edit" method="get" >
                    <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
                    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If I were added the {{  the_button|safe }} I got this error message: TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'safe'. What else could be possible??

Comment: @Peter that's because *safe* filter is not supported on Django 0.96, I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: 0.96 doesn't escape text by default, either, so it's unlikely to be the issue. @Peter, can you include the exact output of your page in your question? It seems unlikely that your snippet is nowhere to be seen in the source, yet still shows up in the rendered page.

Comment: @systempuntoout's advice on a better way to do this is right on target, though. Constructing HTML in your controller and passing it to your template is a bad idea.